# HTML code issue

Tags: html

When I use this code on a blank html page it works fine:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

But when I add it to the below this code It just stops and doesn't connect to the script  upload_file.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
        <link href="Student/ChatterBoxDir/ChatterBox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />     
        <link href="MyCSS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div class="box">

    <div class="header">

        <div class="logo" style="width: 300px; height: 159px">


<img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/background - Teacher.png" width="990" height="181" border="0" alt="">
      </div>

        <div class="auto-style1" style="height: 78px">

            <div class="headerimages">
                <div style="position:absolute; left:555px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/teacher/default.aspx">
                <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/home - teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a>

    </div>  
<div class="headerimages">
                <div style="position:absolute; left:611px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/2012/default.asp">
                <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/gallery - teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a>

    </div>                  
                <div class="headerimages">
                <div style="position:absolute; left:674px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/Teacher/Uploads/show_resources.aspx">
                <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/resources - teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a>
    </div>  
    <div style="position:absolute; left:835px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">
    <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/student/calendar.aspx">
    <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/calendar - teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a>
            </div>  
                <div style="position:absolute; left:753px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/upload picture.html">
            <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/management - teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a> 
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute; left:894px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">        
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/TT/Phone.aspx">
                <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/chat - teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a> 
                </div>
                <div style="position:absolute; left:945px; top:92px; style="width: 28px; height: 28px;">    
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/shop.html">
                <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/Links - Teacher.png" width="28" height="28" /></a>
                </div>
<div style="position:absolute; left:845px; top:150px; style="width: 128px; height: 10px;">
                <a href="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk//ChangePassword/ChangePassword.aspx">
                <img src="http://www.mockcourt.org.uk/pics/change password.png" width="128" height="13" /></a>
                </div>
```

It stops working. I am sure it sis something very silly. Can anyone see where the problem is.

Thanks
Ross

Comment: Where is the form in the complete html code?

Answer (score 2):

You already have a form tag open on the page under the `<body>` tag:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

You can't have a form within a form.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

under closing tag of

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```